# can't get my iFrame to scroll

Tags: javascript, iframe, scroll

I'm building my [personal page](http://static.saezmedia.com/terminal/terminal/examples/), which is a computer with an iframe inside of it's screen with a dummy javascript terminal. My problem is that I can't get the iframe to scroll down while I keep writing on the terminal.

I've tried adding `scrolling="yes"` to the iframe and it doesn't work. I tried using `$(document).scrollTop($(document).height());` in the [iframed page](http://static.saezmedia.com/terminal/terminal/examples/rpc-demo.html) and setting the height of the iframed page to 2000px... none of this worked.

This is the code of the page:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body{
background-image:url('http://api.ning.com/files/B4MPF1W8yyhcpqgtcWbw-UuRX4aul676AQ0rB63HYNkXgQR06pGjZVwjKcwMxGgc/apple2c.big.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
#iframe {
position:relative;
padding-top:35px;
padding-left:144px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="iframe">
<iframe src="http://static.saezmedia.com/terminal/terminal/examples/rpc-demo.html" width="458" height="341" scrolling="auto"></iframe></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you main page: http://static.saezmedia.com/terminal/terminal/examples/rpc-demo.html you have the following css code:

```
jquery.terminal.css:13:

overflow:hidden;
```

this makes the scroll bar non visible. If you remove this the page is scrollable and then you have to automatically scroll to the bottom.

Comment: Actually the terminal code you are using doesn't seem to scroll correctly. Maybe try installing 0.4.17.

Answer (score 0):

If you open it in another window, you won't be able to scroll it either.

That looks like an issue with the site.

However, you may be able to scroll it explicitly by fixing the width/height of the iframe and setting overflow auto on the containing div.